# Python Beautifulsoup strange results

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I was trying to pull the heading of all the products on an amazon search.
It works, but the results are just giving me back the header and footer amazon links.

If I inspect the elements on amazon's source it lookslike the product titles are '' tags wrapped in anchors. However, this doesn't appear to be the case when trying to scrape the data.

```
import requests
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def adverts_trade(max_pages):
    page = 1
    while page <= max_pages:
        url = 'https://www.amazon.co.uk/s/ref=sr_pg_2?rh=n%3A560798%2Cn%3A560834%2Ck%3Acanon+lenses&page=' + str(page) + '&keywords=canon+lenses&ie=UTF8'
        source_code = requests.get(url)
        plain_text = source_code.text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text, "html.parser")
        for link in soup.findAll('a'):
            #href = link.find('h2').get_text()
            print(link)
        page += 1

adverts_trade(10)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amazon doesn't like you scraping data from them.  If you add this line to your code:

```
print(plain_text)
```

You'll see the following:

```
>     <!--
>             To discuss automated access to Amazon data please contact api-services-support@amazon.com.
>             For information about migrating to our APIs refer to our Marketplace APIs at
> https://developer.amazonservices.co.uk/ref=rm_5_sv, or our Product
> Advertising API at
> https://affiliate-program.amazon.co.uk/gp/advertising/api/detail/main.html/ref=rm_5_ac
> for advertising use cases.
>     -->
```

Don't expect for most sites to be able to simply use requests and bs4 to scrape data.   Either use their API or consider Selenium or some other scraping tool that can drive an actual browser.

Comment: I'm surprised that there isn't a more simple workaround other then selenium

Comment: Amazon spends a lot of money getting good quality images, product attributes, and dynamically adjusting prices in real time.  They need to make it as difficult as possible for competitors to scrape that data.  Pretty much all major e-commerce sites do whatever they can to prevent scraping.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to get the title from an  tag's title attribute? Or are you trying to get the title from the H2 child of a  tag?

If you are going the first way then try `print(link['title'])` instead print the whole tag. In beautifulSoup you can access the attributes of a catched anchor as a normal dictionary.